# Battery level prediction model

Tags: python, data, machine-learning, algorithm-analysis

I have the idea of develop a model that predicts the battery charge level of my system for now until the following 5 days. The battery is charged using a solar panel. I am writing my code in Python 2.7 . I am able to measure the battery level in % (%100, 90%, 80%...%10). The model does not be very accurate, %10 error is acceptable.

To predict battery level I have only two parameters, current state of charge in % and the UV radiation level from and scale of 0 to 11 (However higher values than 11 are possible but not likely).

The idea to predict the battery level is to first obtain some empirical data day by day at the same time (2 hours after sunset to get rid of surface charge). The data would have the this format.

> DAY UV   %
>
> 1   6.5  80
>
> 2   8.2  90
>
> 3   4.5  60
>
> ......

I want first to obtain some values for a month and then create and algorithm or something like that to obtain a model or make a prediction of what battery level I will have within 5 days. Thanks to https://openweathermap.org/api I have the prediction of UV radiation for 5 days.

The problem is that I don't know how to manage this information or what tools I can use. To predict that battery level I know that need to look at current battery level and the UV prediction of the following 5 days. But I don't know how to make a model with the obtained data.

I was thinking to get the difference of battery level between to days and calculate the charging/discharging rate with and UV radiation level, but that does not work because charging/discharging rates are not same with %20 as current battery level of %80 as current battery level. I can also make an average UV radiation for the 5 days and try to obtain a linear regression...

Any idea or suggestion is welcomed.

Thanks a lot,

Ander.

Comment: ..your battery has a solar cell charger?

Comment: Yes of course, I forgot to mention that...

Comment: I've understood that battery level is notoriously difficult to determine.  It took some study for modern smart phones to be able to (within reason) accurately represent battery life, as the assumption that battery life is linear with how much charge it has is wrong.  I don't know how you're gauging current battery level, but if it is directly through voltage, then it's not going to be linear even if the charge is.

Comment: This is more a simulation engineering question than a software engineering one. It sounds like you are asking about how to model a physical system, less about how to implement your model in software. While I'm not sure on which site this question might be more appropriate, it is off-topic here.

Comment: It is interesting, but I have to agree with Neil that it is probably harder than you think to come up with an accurate model for something like this. There are lots of non-linear effects, and even the capacity of the battery will not remain constant over time.

Comment: I know that is difficult to predict battery percentage within 5 days, but I want an approximate value. For reading the battery level I use battery voltage based on this tutorial: https://www.otherpower.com/otherpower_battery_metering.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So obviously if you use the battery really hard on day 2 it will run out faster than if you didn't, you have no way to predict that.

Your battery presumably discharges at some minimum rate, so I would base the predictions off the assumption that the device will be on standby.

I will also assume a linear charge and discharge rates

Charge can then be expressed as

```
charge = initialCharge - (dischargeRate * t) + (rechargeRate * t)
```

where

```
rechargeRate = rechargeConstant * UV
```

iterate over the days and you have your prediction.

Comment: The battery consumption is practically the same all the days. And what about dischargeRate, how can I get that?

Comment: @Andermutu you could measure it - just track how fast your battery is drained when you do not charge it.

Comment: With a real solar charger, your `rechargeRate` will probably also depend on other factors in addition to the UV radiation rate - temparature may be relevant, for example.

Comment: @andermutu how long will the device function without any sun?

Comment: Hi @Edwan Without the sun will not function, it will be slept until sunrise with minimum consumption.

Comment: Hi @Hulk, I don't really think temperature is important, because I want an approximation, but in case it is I have no problem getting the temperature. The problem is setting all this variables and create a model.

Comment: @andermutu thats not an answer. imagine its at the north pole at winter. how long before the battery runs out

Comment: @Edwan It is designed to last 2.25 days. Please if you need more information ask please.

Comment: @Andermutu discharegeRate = 0.44 p/d

Comment: Thank you @Edwan , your model seems interesting and I am trying it. I want to know how did you get the 0,44 value, in case of I decide to change the 2.25 days. I also want to know if the rechargeConstant is something I need to get empirically.. Thanks.

Comment: 1/2.25 = 0.44. yes if you want your model to be accurate you will need to calibrate it to the real world device

Comment: @Andermutu also, up vote and accept answer?

Comment: Thanks for your effort helping with this difficult situation. I will adjust the model to the real world I will share the results.